# Java data processing workflow framework

Tags: java, workflow, apache-storm

I've got a data stream, basically its a SQL table with 30-50 records adding each minute. Which needs processing with close to real time speed(the records should be processed in about 10 minutes after appearing in the database). I'd like to use some workflow like solution here to make it easier for me to process all records. I need this solution to have high availability - the system should be working on separate hardware nodes and be fault tolerant if one of the nodes goes down. Basically what will happen is this:

- a new record is added to the database
- the workflow starts processing it
- does some stuff as a result of that processing(sending emails, doing inserts into the database etc.)
- the framework should memorize that the record has been process it

Another requirement is that if there was an error during the processing of one of the records it should not stop the framework from processing the others. It should  just memorize that this particular records needs re-processing.

I've heard that twitter-storm does something similar to this but isn't it an overkill to use it here? As I understand it's main purpose is to process gigantic amounts of data concurrently which I don't really need here at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can build just perfect scalable solution using `Apache Camel` and `ActiveMQ`. Faulty nodes will throw an exception and unprocessed message could be sent back to `AMQ` queue to be processed later (with possibly other node).

Comment: One thing to remember about Storm is that it is fault tolerant.  I'm not sure how fault tolerant you can get if you roll your own processing system.  There are very strong guarantees on data processing in Storm in the face of hardware and other failures.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind Storm does not do persistence, so you would be processing data as a Stream, then do persistence on the end of it (or in the middle, beginning, etc.  Essentially a bolt somewhere in your Topology would write it out).

Storm would solve your problems when it comes to fault tolerance, and guarantees on processing.  But at 30-50 Tuples (the Storm data abstraction), it might indeed be "overkill" to use.  But then the issue becomes how easily you can write your own system that still has the *guarantees* of data processing that Storm has (for instance, if a node in your system goes down, but was in the middle of processing some data, what happens to that data?).  I can tell you that setting up a Topology and running it is very simple.  The abstractions Storm uses are not difficult at all to work with (Streams, Tuples, Bolts and Spouts).  If you haven't already, I recommend watching this tech talk on it:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=biKMS3HILJ4